# WPF query doesn't seem appropriate

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq

I have this application in which report is not working. I am a PHP developer and I can understand the `select * from table` like query but Linq query is new to me.

Even in Linq query there is a join concept but I am not seeing any joins in this query so I am wondering is there anything wrong with this query or is this normal in WPF to use query like that?

```
                var query = from t in dc.TransectionsRemittenances
                            from c in t.CustomerAccounts
                            from b in t.Beneficiaries
                            from bank in b.BeneBankAccounts
                            where t.AgentId == int.Parse(agentId)
                            where t.GbBranchId == GlobalClass.GbBranchID
                            where t.Date == givenDate
                            select new { t, c, b, bank };
```

The actual code is like this:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string agentName = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                DateTime givenDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbDate.Text, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                
                if (cmbAgents.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                {
                    agentId = ((DataRowView)cmbAgents.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                    agentName = ((DataRowView)cmbAgents.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                    //MessageBox.Show(agentId);
                    //------------------------LOAD REPORT--------------------------//

                    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
                    RMSDatabase2DataSet dataset = new RMSDatabase2DataSet();

                    dataset.BeginInit();

                    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
                    DataSet1.AgentFaxDSDataTable dt = new DataSet1.AgentFaxDSDataTable();

                    if (GlobalClass.GbBranchID != 12)
                    {
                        var query = from t in dc.TransectionsRemittenances
                                    from c in t.CustomerAccounts
                                    from b in t.Beneficiaries
                                    where t.AgentId == int.Parse(agentId)
                                    where t.GbBranchId == GlobalClass.GbBranchID
                                    where t.Date == givenDate
                                    select new { t, c, b};

                        foreach (var d in query)
                        {
                                dt.Rows.Add(d.t.ReceiverCurrency, d.t.ReceivedAmount, d.t.Date,
                                d.c.Name, d.b.Name, d.b.FName, d.b.City, d.b.Address);//, "", "", "", "");
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var query = from t in dc.TransectionsRemittenances
                                    from c in t.CustomerAccounts
                                    from b in t.Beneficiaries
                                    from bank in b.BeneBankAccounts
                                    where t.AgentId == int.Parse(agentId)
                                    where t.GbBranchId == GlobalClass.GbBranchID
                                    where t.Date == givenDate
                                    select new { t, c, b, bank };

                        foreach (var d in query)
                        {
                            if (d.t.BeneSource == null)
                            {
                                dt.Rows.Add(d.t.ReceiverCurrency, d.t.ReceivedAmount, d.t.Date,
                                d.c.Name, d.b.Name, d.b.FName, d.b.City, d.b.Address, "", "", "", "");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dt.Rows.Add(d.t.ReceiverCurrency, d.t.ReceivedAmount, d.t.Date,
                                d.c.Name, d.b.Name, d.b.FName, d.b.City, d.b.Address, " (Bank: " + d.bank.BankName + ",",
                                " AccNo-" + d.bank.BankAccountNo + "-", " BCode-" + d.bank.BranchCode, ", " + d.bank.Address + ")");
                            }
                        }
                        //query.ToArray().
                    }
                    
                    reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1"; //Name of the report dataset in our .RDLC file
                    reportDataSource1.Value = dt;

                    
                    this._reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    this._reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
                    this._reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "RMS.rptRemittances.rdlc";

                    ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[2];
                    param[0] = new ReportParameter("para_agent", agentName.ToString());
                    param[1] = new ReportParameter("para_forDate", givenDate.ToString("d/M/yyyy"));

                    this._reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);

                    _reportViewer.RefreshReport();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string messageBoxText = "Enter Date Formate is incorrect, it must be 'MM/DD/YYYY'.\n\n" + ex.Message;
                string caption = "Error";
                MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OK;
                MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Error;
                MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);

            }
        }
```

Is this query OK, and if it is, then how does it work? I mean regarding joins, inner join or left join etc. Plus what is the name of this query, if it's not Linq query what should I look for on the internet?

As I am getting no problem from this query in application developed by previous developer of my company. But I am also not getting any data - that's why I am trying to check this query is OK and want to run it in MSSQL to see if there is any result generating from it. But I am not sure what to do with the joins.

Comment: are you familiar with LinkPad.. try using a tool like that to generate the correct linq query

Comment: @MethodMan
ok. i will try linkpad

Answer (score 1):

Just like in SQL Server, omitting the join clauses in Linq effectively creates a [Cross Join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join), which results in a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

The need for a Cross join is *relatively* rare, but without knowing all the details of what the report is displaying, it's impossible to say whether it is right or wrong.

Also like in SQL, the WHERE clause can effectively transform a Cross Join into an Inner Join, so that may be what was intended.